# Python Float String Formatting Not Working Right

Tags: python, string, formatting, mini-language

I'm pretty sure that I'm doing this correctly but not getting the results that I expect from Python 2.7.3 string formatting mini-language. I'm trying to format the output of a float to 3 integer values and a varying number of decimal values. Everything works except the integer values.

By itself, the following code works to get me 3 integer values...

```
num = 3
value = '{:03}'.format(num)

returns '003'
```

And floats work...

```
num = 3.12345
value = '{:01.2f}'.format(num)

returns '3.12'
```

However, combining the two does not seem to work properly. The decimal precision works, but the integer precision does not...

```
num = '3.12345'
value = '{:03.2f}'.format(num)

returns '3.12'

instead of the expected '003.12'
```

The same is true if I try any of the following formats...

```
value = '{:03.02f}'.format(num)
- or -
value = '{0:3.2f}'.format(num)
- or -
value = '{:3.02f}'.format(num)
- or -
value = '{0:3.02f}'.format(num)
- or -
value = '{0:03.2f}'.format(num)
- or -
value = '{0:03.02f}'.format(num)
- or -
value = '{:0>3.2f}'.format(num)
etc...

Which all return the same '3.12' instead of '003.12'
```

If you're curious about what I'm doing for the varying / dynamic decimal precision, the point is to keep all the values the same length, but different sets of values may not have the same precision. So I take the smaller of the longest precision value or 10 and force the others to match like this..

```
from decimal import Decimal

dVals = [
    abs(Decimal(val1).as_tuple().exponent), # Get the number of decimal points
    abs(Decimal(val2).as_tuple().exponent), # "" ""
    abs(Decimal(val3).as_tuple().exponent), # "" ""
    abs(Decimal(val4).as_tuple().exponent), # "" ""
    ]

    p = max(dVals)  # Get the largest value
    p = min(p, 10)  # Get the smaller of the largest value or 10

vals = [val1, val2, val3, val4]

for val in vals:
    value = '{:0>3.{prec}f}'.format(val, prec = p)
    # do whatever with value here...
```

Again, this all works perfectly, except that the integer value never returns with 3 precision places when I combine it with float precision. So all my efforts to ensure the values output with the same formatted length are all for naught. Ultimately, the output should look similar to...

```
'009.123456700'
'180.101010101'
'054.987654321'
```

Instead, it looks like this...

```
'9.123456700'
'180.101010101'
'54.987654321'
```

In other words, ugly. :-|

At the very least, I would accept the following output...

```
'  9.123456700'
'180.101010101'
' 54.987654321'
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here? Your help is much appreciated!

Regards,

-RMWChaos

Comment: You should try to shorten your question harder...

Comment: Ah, yes, I tend to be a bit prolific thinking more info is better. I will shorten my questions in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The first digit is the total width of the result, not the width before the decimal point.

```
>>> '{:06.2f}'.format(3.12345)
'003.12'
```

Comment: `The first digit is the total width of the result`, including the dot.

Comment: Yep, that was it. First digit is the total length of the output including the decimal point, not just the length of the integer portion of the value. :facepalm: Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
num = '3.12345'
value = '{:03.2f}'.format(num)
```

Here `03` takes into account all digits (including the floating point itself). so you should do something like this:

```
value = '{:06.2f}'.format(num)
```

this will get you: `'003.12'`

count everything in this string `'003.12'`, the result is 6. But you were using 3 which is even less than the count of the minimal representation, which is why you got `'3.12'`